# include a specific part of a header file in C++

Tags: c++

I wonder if I can include a specific part of a header file instead of including whole of a header file!

for Example in Python we can do that like:

```
from math import sqrt
```

which only import sqrt from math class.

Is it anyway to do that in C++?

Comment: No. With some `#if` in the header, possibly, but this looks like a hack.

Comment: https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2019/03/31/modules-2.html

Comment: no, and i suppose there is also no use for that since is compiled...

Comment: But as @drum links, with C++20 modules, it might become possible, with a total new paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of:

```
extern "C" double sqrt(double);
extern "C" int printf(char const*, ...);

int main() {
  printf("sqrt(2) = %f\n", sqrt(2.0));
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDbSV9ABk8tTADlnACNMYhAANlIAB1QhQnNaO0cXN2jY%2BLofP0CnELDI40xTBIYCZmICJOdXd0LiulLygiyA4NCIozKKqpTarubfVtz28IBKI1QHYmQOKUxxAlDaAGodbRs15fRJoPZloQBHCohth13MUc0AZn0ZAEF5xeIVtY3tbWXfAmWo4i%2BqCDIBDlZZoWhCAgAKlIywAdPDLjdNPdkXcvssnMxfBBRqsAOy3O7LH5/egAtaHY7aXHXAAiq20AFYqJpGTZaGsYZSCBBtLCZKNEYTNHjaVJxqxpIz5K5ZPJUNI3vo9PtJtNMAyrpx5ARpHJBaQANYgK5XWHcK7hTh4mScRl4gCcMkZzpU0m4Mr18uk8iEIBkpF1cvGcFgMEQKFQTiieHYZAogKjMbjKFU6k4MltfFjTz9ECCXtIQV85QAntJtaQ0E4nFYCAB5Wiscty0hYTHqdiF/DEIpmABumD9rfmRQci0LX0wktbrDwQWIZbsWELBD%2BTgr4r4dEYLC7PG3ghEEkLSk4KjUGgMBhU879kHGqCiZjow4AtBD0HStHoDNblm%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%2B4u6P%2BQEgWBEHMFBX0UQhECeJxqHWDxmHnthGR4ckKFpDhCTG4VRj0ZR/QGw7JhO00dulex1GW1xHuDBhhX8YJlVtR1cXepJMlyQpwDIMgKmBRpWnFbpPX6YZBXEJq1IGUrlnBldJpmqapdl%2BXq3yP5gW2da2h7VJDqN3id1eRHCWnX6AYXSGgNIJl2UELliZGSm7iYKnpXVdz%2B58zuAv1fFTXMC1UjamHYk/dIPUfP1BCDcNMfLHHCew%2BpBezaQ82Le0K0zmtIAbVtz3105GYZvXHnfZHSXd1ZRc3XLkA0u3kvrt1%2Bj3Nq2hN4/z%2BpfQcxA4gWG4EAA%3D%3D%3D)

There is no way to do that for templates or class definitions though. There is also no way to do that for stuff in `std` namespace for many reasons, one of them being implementations use inline-namespaces there.